# Is my SQL Server 2000 connection string compatible with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, compatibility-level

Currently I have an application in Visual Basic 6.

This application connects to a SQL Server 2000 server using a Data Link file (.UDL) through the OLE DB provider for SQL. The server will be migrated to SQL Server 2012.

Will the connection string that is currently used work for SQL Server 2012?

The connection string is something like:

```
[oledb]
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=XXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXX;
Initial Catalog=SQL2000DB;Data Source=SERVERNAME
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the actual connection string.  I would think it should work unmodified.

Comment: Try to show here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: My doubt arises with the use of SQLNCLI11 since my connection use SQLOLEDB.1. I understand that SQL 2012 native mode use SQLNCLI11.

Comment: It looks like this connection string should work.  Having said that, I would certainly test it by installing SQL Server 2012 on a test server, and attempting to connect to it using the VB6 app.

Comment: The OleDB provider should work; however it doesn't give you access to certain features such as failover mirroring, etc.

Comment: I think we can deal with that. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, it should keep working. You should, if possible, test this using a development server running SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Worth noting that OLE DB is being depreciated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967418.aspx